# Maintaining singletons in Session Spring MVC

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, singleton, session-variables

I have 2 session scoped beans

1)sessionholder1
2)sessionholder2

Both sessionholders have object UserVO in them

```
class SessionHolder1{
private UserVO user = new UserVO();
}

class SessionHolder2{
private UserVO user = new UserVO();
}
```

Now if i change some variable of the userVO in sesionholder1 it gets changed in sessionholder2 too.Is this behavior normal or is this due to bad design?

Is there any work around for this other than using clone() ?Kindly help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store the same UserVO object in both, then of course changing some field in one will change the field in the other. If you want two distinct objects, then create two distinct objects. If one is a copy of the other, the best way is to use a copy constructor:

```
/**
 * Constructs a copy of the given userVO
 */
public UserVO(UserVO userVO) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: hi,as i am creating new userVO() object in both sessionholders,will it still mean the same object?pls clarify..

Comment: No, they will refer to two different objects.

Comment: In the code snippet i have provided,dont i create 2 new objects?still the values get changed in both.

Comment: Maybe you replace those two objects by a single one later. Or maybe those two objects reference another common object that you're modifying. With just those lines of code available, I can only guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot.."Maybe you replace those two objects by a single one later",Exactly what I was doing..Thanks again..